# Endeca XM Facets Issue

Tags: endeca

I am facing a problem like, some times when accessing facets in the Endeca Experience manager, am getting 500 exception.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d22Sd.jpg)

I had to restart ToolsAndFrameworks and do an indexing to resolved this issue.
Is there any clue like why this issue occurs?

Comment: Which version of Endeca? Have you checked the ifcr.log?

Comment: I am using 11.2 for my project

Comment: Hi, I would be glad if anyone give some update on this issue.

Comment: Replicate the problem and add the error from the ifcr.log file into your question as an 'edit'. The most likely cause of your issue is that you have an XM rule that references a dimension value that doesn't exist in the index but can't confirm this without any additional information.